# AWS Lambda is seemingly not highly available when invoked from SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, high-availability

I am invoking a data processing lambda in bulk fashion by submitting ~5k sns requests in an asynchronous fashion. This causes all the requests to hit sns in a very short time. What I am noticing is that my lambda seems to have exactly 5k errors, and then seems to "wake up" and handle the load.

Am I doing something largely out of the ordinary use case here?
Is there any way to combat this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's a combination of concurrency, and the way lambda connects to SNS.

Lambda is only *so* good at automatically scaling up to deal with spikes in load.

Full details are here: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html), but the key points to note that

1. There's an account-wide concurrency limit, which you can ask to be
   raised. By default it's much less than 5k, so that will limit how
   concurrent your lambda could ever become.
2. There's a hard scaling limit (+1000 instances/minute), which means *even* if you've managed to convince AWS to let you have a concurrency limit of 30k, you'll have to be under sustained load for 30 minutes before you'll have that many lambdas going at once.

SNS is a non-stream-based asynchronous invocation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns) so what you see is a lot of errors as each SNS attempts to invoke 5k lambdas, but only the first X (say 1k) get through, but they keep retrying. The queue then clears concurrently at your initial burst (typically 1k, depending on your region), +1k a minute until your reach maximum capacity.

Note that SNS only retries three times at intervals (AWS is a bit sketchy about the intervals, but it is probably based on the `retry: delay` the service returns, so should be approximately intelligent); I suggest you setup a DLQ to make sure you're not dropping messages because the time for the queue to clear.

While your pattern is not a *bad* one, it seems like you're very exposed to the concurrency issues that surround lambda.

An alternative is to use a stream based event-source (like Kinesis), which processes in batches at a set concurrency (e.g. 500 records per lambda, concurrent by shard count, rather than 1:1 with SNS), and waits for each batch to finish before processing the next.

Comment: thank you. I suspect you mean SNS in your third to last paragraph. I had tried SQS actually, but found it auto scales much slower than SNS. Sounds like Kinesis might be the way to go

Comment: You're right- I did. SQS is poll based so it takes a minute to react to changes. Although it might not be important- Kinesis is also ordered. Although you have less control over failure (i.e. either the whole catch can be processed or it can't).

Comment: What about writing all the records to s3 and putting event triggers to lambda? I may have to try that out...

Comment: That depends how you do it, if you write 5k tiny files all at once then you'll see the same problem as with SNS (it's exactly the same type of event source). If you write one 5k file then you'll have one lambda to process it, which means it's up to you to make sure you can do that in memory (I expect you'll be fine on that count). If your plan is to batch it, then you'd be better using Kinesis directly (or Firehose if having it in S3 is important to you), rather than managing the batching yourself. Good luck!